# Can I install both FF4 and FF 3.6 simulataneously?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Firefox 4 Beta alongside Firefox 3.6?](https://superuser.com/questions/160986/install-firefox-4-beta-alongside-firefox-3-6)

I am doing web development and I have Firefox 4 and I need to test in Firefox 3.6 with Firebug. Can I install both Firefox 4 and Firefox 3.6?

Comment: Same exact solution applies as with [Install Firefox 4 Beta alongside Firefox 3.6](http://superuser.com/questions/160986/). Nothing changed in the dual installation procedure between the beta and the final release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **run different versions of Firefox,** (among other apps) **in your browser, without downloading them**, using [**Spoon**](http://spoon.net/).  Give it a try...

> Bring your apps to the cloud - Spoon virtualization lets you run desktop apps anywhere with no installs...  The Spoon plugin is an extension to your browser that lets you run apps from the Spoon web site and other Spoon Servers.  You need to have the Spoon plugin to run Spoon apps.

*Note: I am not affiliated with this product in any way, shape, or form.*

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install both Firefox 4 and Firefox 3.6. Get the portable version for the release you need: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable/localization

There are more complicated solutions using the Profile Manager, but running a portable version is much faster.